# How to loop over multiple sql databases where names increment by one?

Tags: sql-server

I want to add a user to 100 databases where database names increment by one.

```
use database0001
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'user', 'accessman'; 

use database0002
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'user', 'accessman'; 
...
use database0100
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'user', 'accessman';
```

and so on.

There are other databases on the server whose permissions should not be changed.

Comment: [Making a more reliable and flexible sp_MSforeachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a great answer and there are better ways of doing this but this is also *a* way to do this. If this is just a single user which you want to add in *all* the USER databases then here is very simple script that will generate script which you can run in SSMS window and it will add the user in all the databases.

`select 'use ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '; EXEC sp_addrolemember ''user'', ''accessman''; '  from sys.databases where database_id not in (1,2,3,4)`

It generates the script like below. Make sure before running the query you press `Ctrl + T`

```
use [AdventureWorks2016]; EXEC sp_addrolemember 'user', 'accessman'; 
use [ReportServer$SQL2016]; EXEC sp_addrolemember 'user', 'accessman'; 
use [ReportServer$SQL2016TempDB]; EXEC sp_addrolemember 'user', 'accessman';
```

let me know how this goes.